# Retrieve Print history

Tags: logs, printing, cups

i am trying to retrieve print history for feb 16th when i go into
http://localhost:631 and cups/jobs I can see the print jobs but there is no option to reprint?

Comment: I tried the following in terminal

Comment: lp -i 105 -H restart but says no job exists ??

Answer (score 0):

You can use `lp` tool.

Check the id of a job i.e. 879897, then do:

`lp -i 879897 -H restart`

And the job will be printed again but on the same printer !

If you want to print it on another printer, check the name of the new printer (lpstat -p), and do:

```
 sudo lpmove 879897 new_printer
 lp -i 879897 -H restart
```

Comment: Thank you for you answer - what is an lp tool and where can I get it? Sorry I'm not computer savvy.